# How to get ExecutionLogStorage table data by web service in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to get `ExecutionLogStorage` table data by web service method.

However I am not sure if any method in order to find data from `ExecutionLogStorage` in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Report Server web service does not contain any methods to return report execution history, which I assume is what you are looking for in the ExecutionLogStorage table, so you will need to query this data directly. Note that Microsoft does not recommend querying ReportServer system tables so you can use one of several views available e.g. `dbo.ExecutionLog3`